# What are WEBSITE_DAAS_STORAGE_CONNECTIONSTRING and WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

In my Azure web app, in the Environment variables it has a value for `WEBSITE_DAAS_STORAGE_CONNECTIONSTRING` and `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION`. I didn't create these.

What do these do and do I need to every change them?

Comment: What is the framework and version of your web app?

Comment: `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` is the default setting which is available for all the app service.It specfies the Node version of the app.How you have deployed the app ?

Comment: @Harshitha I deployed via Visual Studio. And it's a Blazor (ASP.NET) app so doesn't use Node.js.

Comment: Even if you don't use,this setting will be available once you create app service.

Comment: Do you have any settings in your local appsettings.json file?

Comment: @Harshitha yes but not those values. Thank you for your comprehensive answer.

Comment: Hope this gave clear Idea about the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` setting will be created by default for the Azure App Services created in Windows Environment.

- And I have checked that it is available for both .NET 7 and 8 Versions.
- It will be set for apps deployed from Visual studio only.

[image]

- If the app is created from portal, it has different settings.

[image]

- You can see the Linux App service does not have this setting.

[image]

As mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/reference-app-settings?tabs=kudu%2Cdotnet#:%7E:text=WEBSITE_NPM_DEFAULT_VERSION), it specifies the npm version of the App Service.

> Default npm version the app is using.

`WEBSITE_DAAS_STORAGE_CONNECTIONSTRING`, As per the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/reference-app-settings?tabs=kudu%2Cdotnet#:%7E:text=Crash%20Monitoring.-,WEBSITE_DAAS_STORAGE_SASURI,-During%20crash%20monitoring) this option is for Crash Monitoring.

- In `Diagnose and solve problems` => `Diagnostic Tools` => `Crash Monitoring` , I have configured the Storage Account.

[image]

- `WEBSITE_DAAS_STORAGE_CONNECTIONSTRING` with the configured Storage Account is added in my settings.

[image]

- I have removed `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` and I am able to run the app without any issue.
- You can safely remove `WEBSITE_DAAS_STORAGE_CONNECTIONSTRING` setting to stop the Crash Monitoring.